# Question about geometric series when $a = 1$ and $r=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb N$ such that $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$ and $A\ne B$. Is it possible that $$\sum_{i\in A} \frac{1}{2^i}=\sum_{j\in B} \frac{1}{2^j}$$

Comment: It would be interesting if it was a restricted for a finite set

Comment: It would be much more interested if $A\cup B = N$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \mathbb N \setminus \{0,2\}$, and note

$$\frac12 + \frac14 = \frac 12 + \left(\frac18 + \frac1{16} + \dots\right)$$

Comment: Where did the $\frac{1}{2}$ on the right side come from?

Comment: It comes from $j=1\in B$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, then it is clearly impossible.

Let $d = \max(A,B)$ and multiply both summations by $2^d$.

---

**Edit**
It was suggested to first subtract the elements common to both $A$ and $B$.  That is unnecessary.  In the analysis below, which depends on constructed numbers base 2, for the constructed numbers to be distinct, it is sufficient that there is at least one difference in the binary digits.

---

Then you have two distinct base 2 representations, so they must represent distinct integers.

Therefore, since each summation is $\frac{\text{distinct integer}}{2^d}$, 
the summations must be different.

Allowing one of the sets to be infinite is similar to recognizing that
$0.999\cdots = 1.0.$

Comment: nice observation